# Errors creating Onos project with maven archetype

Tags: java, sdn, onos

I used the following command and created a default Onos application = `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.onosproject -DarchetypeArtifactId=onos-bundle-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.4.0 -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=onos-app -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

This is pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  ~ Copyright 2022 Open Networking Foundation
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

    4\.0.0
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onos-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    
    <description>ONOS OSGi bundle archetype</description>
    <url>http://onosproject.org</url>
    
    <properties>
        <onos.app.name>org.foo.app</onos.app.name>
        <onos.app.title>Foo App</onos.app.title>
        <onos.app.origin>Foo, Inc.</onos.app.origin>
        <onos.app.category>default</onos.app.category>
        <onos.app.url>http://onosproject.org</onos.app.url>
        <onos.app.readme>ONOS OSGi bundle archetype.</onos.app.readme>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onlab-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onlab-misc</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>onos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The AppComponent.java =

```java
package org.foo.app;

import org.onosproject.cfg.ComponentConfigService;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Modified;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.onlab.util.Tools.get;

/******
* Skeletal ONOS application component.
*/
@Component(immediate = true,
service = {SomeInterface.class},
property = {
  "someProperty=Some Default String Value",
})
public class AppComponent implements SomeInterface {
  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  /** Some configurable property. */
  private String someProperty;

  @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY)
  protected ComponentConfigService cfgService;

  @Activate
  protected void activate() {
  cfgService.registerProperties(getClass());
  log.info("Started");
  }

  @Deactivate
  protected void deactivate() {
  cfgService.unregisterProperties(getClass(), false);
  log.info("Stopped");
  }

  @Modified
  public void modified(ComponentContext context) {
  Dictionary\<?, ?\> properties = context != null ? context.getProperties() : new Properties();
  if (context != null) {
  someProperty = get(properties, "someProperty");
  }
  log.info("Reconfigured");
  }

  @Override
  public void someMethod() {
  log.info("Invoked");
  }
}
```

The error I get is like this =

```
onur@staj2:~/Downloads/foo-app$ mvn compile 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.foo:foo-app >---------------------------
[INFO] Building foo-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] -------------------------------[ bundle ]-------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce-maven) @ foo-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce-java) @ foo-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- onos:2.4.0:swagger (swagger) @ foo-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- onos:2.4.0:cfg (cfg) @ foo-app ---
[INFO] Generating ONOS component configuration catalogues...
[INFO] Processing property someProperty|STRING|Some Default String Value|Some configurable property. ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ foo-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/onur/Downloads/foo-app/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ foo-app ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/onur/Downloads/foo-app/target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (17.0.8). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (https://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (https://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneJavacPlugin (in unnamed module @0x120350eb) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x120350eb
        at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneJavacPlugin.init(ErrorProneJavacPlugin.java:38)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask.initPlugin(BasicJavacTask.java:255)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask.initPlugins(BasicJavacTask.java:229)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.prepareCompiler(JavacTaskImpl.java:204)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:101)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348)
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.257 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-08T10:00:22+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project foo-app: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Please help to solve the errors, I've been dealing with this for a long time, I couldn't find where I made a mistake.